# shell script: My crontab script does not run

Tags: bash, shell, cron

Im trying to run a simple script with crontab and it does not run, I tried to write the output to log but it doesn't write anything, here is what i did:

```
crontab -e
```

then I have added my shell script (Which it running perfect if I run it manually):

```
*/1 * * * * /script/check.sh > /script/output.log
```

(yes, I need to run this script every minute), its simple script that check if another script is running.

any idea why its not running from the crontab but indeed running well from console?

BTW: I have direct admin, and if Im running it from there it running well, But I need root permissions, thats why Im using the crontab.

Thanks in advance!

Eran.

Comment: Does the script depend on environment variables, such as `$PATH`, that are set in `.profile`? No shell startup scripts are run when a program is run from `cron`.

Comment: If you just put `echo running` in the script, does it work?

Comment: it using grep only, I have added this anyway: SHELL=/bin/sh
   PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin, its not help..

Comment: Are you sure you have the path to the script correct? Are there any messages in the system log?

Comment: actually no, I can't see nothing it output.log

Comment: yes, the path is correct its the first folder /script/, checking the system log..

Comment: I can see it in system log: Jul  4 08:35:01 eranln CROND[29178]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/directadmin/dataskq)
Jul  4 08:35:01 eranln CROND[29179]: (root) CMD (echo "running" > /script/output.log)

Comment: So you see the log message about `echo running`, but not for `/script/check.sh`?

Comment: Please flag your question for migration to unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I will, Thanks anyway @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it, Im not sure why, but I had to add "sh" before my script to make it work, anyway its working fine now, thanks!:

> */1 * * * * sh /script/check.sh > /script/output.log

Comment: If that made it work, the script is probably either missing its [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (the first line of the script should be either `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`, depending on whether you use any bash extensions in the script), or it may not have execute permissions set (`chmod +x /script/check.sh` should fix that).

Comment: ...i wonder: `then I have added my shell script (Which it running perfect if I run it manually)`.